# How to maintain order when iterating over a Map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have the following map:

```clj
(def tmp-cust-data {:customers
                    {:january [1 0 2 0 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :february [0 1 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :march [0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :april [1 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
                     :may [1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :june [1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :july [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :august [1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :september [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :october [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                     :november [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
                     :december [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]}})
```

When I do something like `doseq` over that map, I notice the order isn't preserved:

```clj
(doseq [[k v] (:customers tmp-cust-data)] (println k))
```

Is there a proper way to iterate over a map while preserving the order?

Comment: did you try a [sorted map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-map)

Comment: @nlloyd A sorted map sorts its entries by its keys, it does not preserve insertion order. There are libraries such as `org.flatland/ordered` and `frankiesardo/linked` which provide map implementations which do preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ordered version of the map.

```
(def tmp-cust-data {:customers
                    (flatland.ordered.map/ordered-map
                        [[:january [1 0 2 0 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:february [0 1 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:march [0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:april [1 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:may [1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:june [1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:july [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:august [1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:september [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:october [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:november [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
                         [:december [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]])})
```

Answer (score 3):

A hash map is *inherently unordered* by definition. You can *choose* an order for your keys and you can then iterate over those keys in order and access the hash map values, but the hash map itself cannot possibly have "an order".

Comment: of course you're right about hash maps, but maybe an [array-map](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#ArrayMaps) would work for a constrained use case

Comment: The OP's question has twelve entries -- eight is the threshold at which array maps will turn into regular hash maps as more elements are added, so there are plenty of operations you might perform on an array-map that will turn it into an unordered hash map so that really isn't a good solution.