# How to order keys in Clojure map? Ideally sort them against a vector of keys

Tags: clojure

I found different solutions on how to order a map by values, but none around how I can get the key to appear in a certain order.

We know that the keys are auto sorted and don't appear in the way they were inserted, but could we force it afterwards somehow?

For example, given a map:
`(def my-map {:one 1 :two 2 :three 3 :four 4 :five 5})`,
I would like to change the order in which they're displayed.

The desired keys are in the vector
`(def sorted-keys-here [:four :three :five :two :one])`

Such that, I would like the map to appear after the sort-fn applied as:

`=> {:four 4 :three 3 :five 5 :two 2 :one 1}`

The keys are always fixed, and I'd be doing this to a vector of maps using `map`, but I couldn't get this sort to be applied.

Any ideas?

(Edit: The problem isn't that the order isn't maintained. The actual problem is how to conform keys in a map to a specified order. The map would be coming from somewhere else and be going through transformations in the middle, so it's not possible to get it in the right order from the start anyway).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maintain order when iterating over a Map in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293651/how-to-maintain-order-when-iterating-over-a-map-in-clojure)

Comment: @akond Not really! They seem to have solved it by using ordered-map during creation, but my use case requires creating a map through calculations, and they might arrive in any order! So I have to consult an external vector to sort them against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like the following:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest 
  (let [keys-ordered  [:one :two :three :four :five :six]
        keys->idx     (zipmap keys-ordered (range))
        order-fn      (fn [x y] (< (keys->idx x) (keys->idx y))) ; a comparitor
        m             {:one 1 
                       :two 2
                       :three 3
                       :four 4
                       :five 5 
                       :six 6}

        m-sorted-norm (into (sorted-map) m)
        m-sorted-custom (into (sorted-map-by order-fn) m) ]

    (spyx-pretty m-sorted-norm)
    (spyx-pretty m-sorted-custom)
  ))
```

which will produce:

```
m-sorted-norm =>
{:five 5, :four 4, :one 1, :six 6, :three 3, :two 2}

m-sorted-custom =>
{:one 1, :two 2, :three 3, :four 4, :five 5, :six 6}
```

using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

However, please remember that sorted maps only ever make a difference in how they print at the terminal.  For all other uses, ***there is no benefit*** to using a sorted map (and there can be much pain in maintaining them).

Please see also [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet.

### Update

If all you need is to export some maps to CSV, you may find the [tupelo.csv](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.07.08/doc/readme) library useful.  The unit tests [show the code in action](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/csv.clj#L210).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!!

I kinda guessed that comparators would be the way to go but I didn't really understand it and got intimidated to try! Time to dig in. :D

Comment: Btw I needed this to work because I needed to export the columns to CSV and wanted them in the right order! Hadn't needed this for anything else so far either!

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will get you there

```
(def my-map {:one 1 :two 2 :three 3 :four 4 :five 5})
(map my-map [:four :three :five :two :one])  ;
```

you can put your generic vector of keys on the fly

```
(def vector-seq [:two :one])
(map my-map vector-seq)  ; this will return list
(mapv my-map vector-seq)  ; this will return vector
```

or you can do is "weight" the input vector

```
(let [my-map {:one 1 :two 2 :three 3 :four 4 :five 5}
      vector-seq [:five :three :two :four :one]
      weight (apply hash-map (interleave vector-seq (range (count vector-seq))))]
  (into 
        (sorted-map-by 
            (fn [key1 key2]
                (> (get weight key2)
                  (get weight key1))))
        my-map ))
```

this will produce a `sorted-map` with sequence of `vector-seq`

Comment: Thanks! This returns a vector of values in the desired order, and the resultant map can be achieved by `zipmap`!

Comment: It actually didn't work for a larger range of keys. For a map containing 10 key-value pairs for example. So I guess zipmap reorders itself as well after a limit?

Comment: Thanks! The comparator approach did work, as suggested in the other answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please also consider the following approach of getting a map with keys sorted as described in a vector:

```clj
(defn get-map-sorted-by-order
  [some-map keys-order]
  (into (sorted-map-by (fn [first-key second-key]
                         (< (.indexOf keys-order first-key)
                            (.indexOf keys-order second-key))))
        some-map))
```

It uses the Java's `.indexOf`. However, I find it very convenient.

```clj
(get-map-sorted-by-order
 {:hello "Hello", :world "World", :comma-space ", ", :exclamation "!"}
 [:hello :comma-space :world :exclamation])
```

Leads to the following result:

```clj
{:hello "Hello", :comma-space ", ", :world "World", :exclamation "!"}
```